# How is the weak law of large numbers applied here?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$ with $d>1$
- $\lambda^d$ denote the Lebesuge measure on $\mathcal B\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$
- $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ be positive and $$\pi(x):=\prod_{i=1}^df(x_i)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$ with $X_\ast\operatorname P=\pi\lambda^d$

Now, let $$g(x):=\sum_{i=2}^d\frac1{d-1}\left|\frac{f'(x_i)}{f(x_i)}\right|^2\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$

Note that $$\operatorname E\left[g(X)\right]=\int\frac{\left|f'\right|^2}f\:{\rm d}\lambda^1=:I.\tag1$$

> How can we apply the weak law of large numbers to obtain $$\operatorname P\left[\left|g(X)-I\right|>\varepsilon\right]\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\tag2$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What were your attempts solving this?

Comment: @James I don't have any idea. My problem is that $X$ with varying $d$ is not a sequence of independent random variables, so I don't see how the weak law of large numbers can be applied here.

Comment: wait, how is this not the weak law of large numbers? $g$ is literally the average of $\frac{f'}{f}$, which are independent of each other.

Comment: @mathworker21 Rename $X$ to $X_d$. Why is $(X_d)_{d\in\mathbb N}$ independent? Clearly, $$\operatorname P\left[X_{d_1+d_2}\in B_1\times\cdots\times B_{d_1+d_2}\right]=\prod_{i=1}^{d_1}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\lambda^1\prod_{i=1}^{d_2}\int_{B_{d_1+i}}f\:{\rm d}\lambda^1=\operatorname P\left[X_{d_1}\in B_1\times\cdots\times B_{d_1}\right]\operatorname P\left[X_{d_2}\in B_{d_1+1}\times\cdots\times B_{d_1+d_2}\right],$$ but I don't see why the left-hand side is equal to $\operatorname P\left[\left(X_{d_1},X_{d_2}\right)\in B_1\times\cdots\times B_{d_1+d_2}\right]$.

Comment: Okay, I think we don't need $(X_d)_{d\in\mathbb N}$ but that for any fixed $d\in\mathbb N$ the components $X_{d,\:1},\ldots,X_{d,\:d}$ of $X_d$ are independent, right? However, this is not a direct application of the weak law of large numbers, since $X_{d,\:1},\ldots,X_{d,\:d}$ is not an infinite sequence and depends on the upper limit $d$ of the summation. Why can we apply it?

Comment: @mathworker21 We cannot apply it directly, but it's still trivial; you're right. I was a bit confused about the setup.

Comment: Yea, I think making everything formal might be a bit annoying, but intuitively, it's WLLN